# Earthquakes Triangulation

Tags: geometry

So I was thinking, how do geologists even KNOW where earthquakes come from.

I searched it up, and they used triangulation: which was using three (or probably more) sources measuring the force (or seismic activity) from different locations to estimate the epicenter's location.

I wanted to try something like this myself.

So let's say we have four points, $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$, $(x_e,y_e)$. We also have the seismic activity, which would geometrically be equal to about $r$.

We only have two unknowns, which are the coordinates of the epicenter.

Why do we need triangulation? Why can't we determine it from just two? My guess is that the intersection of two circles has two points, so we need a third circle to determine the actual point of the epicenter? Is this correct  reasoning?

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elemental's answer is good but I'd like to give a slightly more abstract perspective.  Take the line between two stations, and reflect the entire world across that line.  So long as the signals you are measuring have no directional component (e.g. only measuring intensity of vibration, frequency, arrival time, duration) then they will be invariant under this reflection.  So there is no way for those two sensors by themselves to distinguish between the original world and the mirror world.

It may seem that adding a third sensor is overkill to resolve the ambiguity.  But I would argue that these signals are probably quite noisy to begin with, and the redundancy is useful in practice or else your calculation will be highly susceptible to deviations.  I would view additional sensors (possibly with conflicting information) not as a burden to reconcile but as valuable data to that can be used to refine the model.

Comment: So would most earthquakes be detected with even more than three stations?

Comment: @SakethMalyala Honestly, I'm not the right person to ask what seismologists are actually doing.  But a quick Google search shows this map https://www.iris.edu/hq/programs/gsn/maps (Figure 5).  There are a lot of places in the world with 5 or more stations located nearby, and some particularly interesting regions (California, parts of China) which have 8 or maybe 10 stations.  And I imagine there could be other sensor networks out there.  In the real world there are outages and so it pays to be able to sustain the loss of a station.

Answer (score 3):

Two points *always* create a line. For every point that does not lie on that line, there will always be exactly one other point that is the same distance from the two points that created the line. This can be shown by making a line with two points ($a$ and $b$), drawing a point $x$ anywhere not on that line, and then drawing two circles that intersect $x$, one with center point $a$ and the other with center point $b$. The two circles will intersect at two points, and it is impossible to tell which is $x$ if you only know the lengths of line $bx$ and line $ax$. This does not apply when $x$ is on line $ab$ because the circles will intersect at a single point. Feel free to try it yourself.

Additionally, if you only know the direction of the source, then the two point system will actually work for all points not on the line, but will fail unless the epicenter is one of those points.

Comment: So the line of mirroring is the one that passes through each center of both circles?

Comment: @SakethMalyala correct. I should also mention that unless all of the center points are not on the same line, this problem will still occur regardless of how many center points you have.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the signals received at two stations will give a hyperbola for possible locations of the epicenter. I don't see any way that circles would enter into it. Adding stations gives additional hyperbolas. A third station can resolve the two point ambiguity from just using two.  There are many descriptions of the Loran radio navigation system online which explain the mathematics involved - uses the same principal.

It's harder to make the calculations with sound rather than with radio, though. The signal received at a given station generally will travel through a different medium and have a different speed than the same signal as seen at other stations. It's also possible to get duplicates of a single signal at a single station when it travels by two different paths.

Comment: Why would it make a hyperbola?

Comment: Isn't that for when you know the difference between the times?

Comment: According to what I read on the Internetz, a single station can use the difference in propagation speeds of S and P waves to infer a distance to epicenter.  This is why one can (approximately) determine a circle from just one station, rather than a hyperbola in the case of locating a signal of known speed and unknown starting time arriving at two stations.

Comment: @SakethMalyala The short answer to your second question, which  supersedes the first: yes.